# Not able to parse the object in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, object

I am not able to parse the below object in C# .NET. I am getting parsing object error.

**messageBody (in String format - I am getting this below object in string format)**

```
{
  "Type" : "Nti_1",
  "MessageId" : "c1b7cd5b-3099-532e-9539-91376eea607b",
  "SequenceNumber" : "10000000000000128000",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:Project1-SNS.fifo",
  "Message" : "{'Prop1':'202020','Prop2':'Hi-I again reached','Prop3':'Testing String'}",
  "Timestamp" : "2023-02-05T07:35:15.905Z",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxx:PushNotification-SNS.fifo:08d0fac2-ac0f-4ff9-b583-61024a98672d",
  "MessageAttributes" : {
    "EventType" : {"Type":"String.Array","Value":"["SMS","ArialRoot"]"}
  }
}
```

Below is the classes created to parse above object

```
public class ParentObject
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
    public string SequenceNumber { get; set; }

    public string TopicArn { get; set; }

    public ChildObject Message { get; set; }
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

    public string UnsubscribeURL { get; set; }

    public string MessageAttributes { get; set; }
}


public class ChildObject
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the code which I am trying to parse the object

```
ParentObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParentObject>(messageBody)
```

I dont know what I am missing to parse the string to specified above object.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: `Message` is an object in your type and a strig in your JSON. And `MessageAttributes` the other way round.

Comment: And `"Value":"["SMS","ArialRoot"]"` is not even valid JSON

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly single quotes are not valid in json (as you have in the content of the `message` field.

Comment: @fredrik they are valid here as part of the string value

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, but the OP clearly attempts to parse it... which would not work as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you json is not valid, you can fix it using replace string

```
messageBody = messageBody.Replace("\"[","[").Replace("]\"","]");
```

also you Message property is string, if you want to make it json you have to fix it too

```
messageBody = messageBody.Replace("'", "\"").Replace("\"{", "{").Replace("}\"", "}");
ParentObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParentObject>(messageBody);
```

or you can fix a Message property using this code

```
JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(messageBody);
jObj["Message"] = JObject.Parse((string) jObj["Message"]);
ParentObject obj = jObj.ToObject<ParentObject>();
```

also fix the classes

```
public class ParentObject
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
    public string SequenceNumber { get; set; }
    public string TopicArn { get; set; }
    public Message Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string UnsubscribeURL { get; set; }
    public MessageAttributes MessageAttributes { get; set; }
}
public class EventType
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<string> Value { get; set; }
}

public class MessageAttributes
{
    public EventType EventType { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

but it is better if you fix a message body in the source to this one

```
{
  "Type" : "Nti_1",
  "MessageId" : "c1b7cd5b-3099-532e-9539-91376eea607b",
  "SequenceNumber" : "10000000000000128000",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:Project1-SNS.fifo",
  "Message" : {"Prop1":"202020","Prop2":"Hi-I again reached","Prop3":"Testing String"},
  "Timestamp" : "2023-02-05T07:35:15.905Z",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxx:PushNotification-SNS.fifo:08d0fac2-ac0f-4ff9-b583-61024a98672d",
  "MessageAttributes" : {
    "EventType" : {"Type":"String.Array","Value":["SMS","ArialRoot"]}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am getting this error after editing the code --- Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'MessageAttributes', line 9, position 25.

Comment: @HardikParmar All this code was tested and working properly. You have to check your json, it must be different from the one you published.

Comment: Yes. Serge it was my mistake. Your code works properly and its wonderful that you have solved my problem. I was stuck from last 3 days in this point. Thank you very much @serge

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a C# class that matches the structure of the JSON

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MyClass
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
    public string SequenceNumber { get; set; }
    public string TopicArn { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string UnsubscribeURL { get; set; }
    public MessageAttributes MessageAttributes { get; set; }
}

public class MessageAttributes
{
    public EventType EventType { get; set; }
}

public class EventType
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize the JSON string

```
MyClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

Comment: I am still getting the error - Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'MessageAttributes', line 9, position 25.

Answer (score 0):

MessageAttributes is a string in your .net type and an object in your json.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var parent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParentObject>(messageBody);
var child = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChildObject>(parent.Message);
parent.Message = child;
```